# Weblogic 10.3.5 403 Forbidden

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, weblogic-10.x

In weblogic 10.3.5 I get 403--Forbidden after deploy application, but not exceptions or stack-traces in logs, or stdout. Application(spring) deployed on managed server which working on jdk 8. Also, the application is a web application. How do I get an exception?

Comment: Have you turned up the debug log level in the weblogic admin console? Have you looked at the audit logs? You can also redirect stderr and stdout to the log file inside the admin console `Servers -> Server Name -> Logging -> Advanced Section` There has to be an error somewhere...

Comment: Yes, I enabled debug log-level and redirect stderr and stdout to log. But exceptions do not appear. I also tried to run from the command line weblogic.